# Fill input field and submit with cURL?

Tags: forms, curl, https

There is a website `www.example.com` where I can enter a code into an input field. And if the code is correct I get redirected to the next site `www.example.com/rightCode`. Is it possible to do this with curl?

Comment: Yes, it's possible to do this with cURL.

Comment: it's not clear what you wanna do. The check or just calling the rightCode page ?

Comment: @ceejayoz Can you maybe point me in the right direction? I am very new to http requests and curl

Comment: @ivan.rosina I want to fill out the form and submit using curl

Comment: @vonhact Sure! https://curl.haxx.se/docs/

Comment: @ceejayoz What should I look for? Is it a form I am filling out, what exactly is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: @vonhact You should read through the docs. One section is titled "HTTP scripting", which is exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

if the form method call the rightCode in GET (method attribute) just add parameter (input field name) in request url.

curl "http://domain/rightCode?code=xxxx"

Comment: In comment I asked infos, this seems the nearest solution, Thanks for minus